# Is there soething wrong with my coding?

Tags: c++

This coding is in C++ language, basically I just started to learn this language, so I'm not very good in coding.. Hope someone will help me..

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

char name[50], status[3];
int type;
float price, discount, total;

cout << "Please enter patient's name : ";
cin >> name ;
cout << "Please enter patient's status [Children(C) | Adult(A)] : ";
cin >> status ;
cout << "Please enter type of treatment[Restoration(1) | Extraction(2) | Scaling(3) : ";
cin >> type ;

if(status=="C" || status=="c"){
if(type==1){
  price = 6.0;
  discount = price * 0.90;}
else if(type==2){
  price = 15.5;
  discount = price * 0.90;}
else{
  price = 4.0;
  discount = price * 0.90;}}
else if(status=="A" || status =="a"){
if(type==1){
  price = 7.5;
  discount = price * 0.95;}
else if(type==2){
  price = 18.0;
  discount = price * 0.95;}
else{
  price = 5.5;
  discount = price * 0.95;}}

cout << "        \n\n                                   HUSNA DENTAL"<<endl;
cout << "      ===================================================================="<<endl;
cout << "                  Name                   : "<<name<<endl;
cout << "                  Type of treatment      : "<<type<<endl;
cout << "                  Payment before discount: "<<price<<endl;
cout << "                  Payment after discount : "<<(total=price-discount)<<endl;
cout << "      ===================================================================="<<endl;

getch();

}
```

the output is :

Please enter patient's name : Deena

Please enter patient's status [Children(C) | Adult(A)] : A

Please enter type of treatment[Restoration(1) | Extraction(2) | Scaling(3) : 1

```
                               HUSNA DENTAL
  ====================================================================
              Name                   : Deena
              Type of treatment      : 1
              Payment before discount: 0
              Payment after discount : -1.00061e-37
  ====================================================================
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I think the `Payment after discount : -1.00061e-37` is the implied problem.

Comment: Your title is the first problem I see.

Comment: If the problem is with Payment after discount, what happens when status is not 'c' or 'C'?

Comment: try initializing price to something such as 200.0 and see if there's an issue with your conditions being hit at all

Comment: `char name[50]` What happens if the user accidentally enter a program over 50 character that hijacks your computer? but seriously use `std::string` instead of char arrays.

Comment: `conio.h` isn't exactly the best header to include. I recommend just running it from a console.

Answer (score 4):

```
status=="C" || status=="c"
```

You are comparing two pointers for equality here. I don't think that's what you meant to do. Did you mean something like `status[0] == 'c'`? Or `strcmp(status, "C") == 0`?

Or, better yet, since this is tagged C++, why not use std::string and make your life easy?

Comment: This is the C++ version of `==` vs. `equals`. It makes me cry too :__(

Comment: I've tried the `status=="C" || status=="c"` but it still can't output the price and payment after discount,. just when user enter `C` , the price will be displayed and calculated based on the type given..

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name, status;
    int type = 0;
    cout << "Please enter patient's name : ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Please enter patient's status [Children(C) | Adult(A)] : ";
    cin >> status;
    cout << "Please enter type of treatment[Restoration(1) | Extraction(2) | Scaling(3) : ";
    cin >> type;

    float price = 0.0f, discount = 0.0f;
    if (status == "C" || status == "c") {
        if      (type == 1) { price = 6.0f;  discount = price * 0.90f; }
        else if (type == 2) { price = 15.5f; discount = price * 0.90f; }
        else if (type == 3) { price = 4.0f;  discount = price * 0.90f; }
    }
    else if (status == "A" || status == "a") {
        if      (type == 1) { price = 7.5f;  discount = price * 0.95f; }
        else if (type == 2) { price = 18.0f; discount = price * 0.95f; }
        else if (type == 3) { price = 5.5f;  discount = price * 0.95f; }
    }

    cout
        <<         "            HUSNA DENTAL"
        << endl << "===================================================================="
        << endl << "            Name                   : " << name
        << endl << "            Type of treatment      : " << type
        << endl << "            Payment before discount: " << price
        << endl << "            Payment after discount : " << discount
        << endl << "===================================================================="
        << endl;
}
```

Comment: thanyou, btw what `f` is supposed to mean in `price = 7.5f;  discount = price * 0.95f;` ?

Comment: f suffix tells the compiler which is a double and which is a float. It interprets 7.5 as a double and 7.5f as a float.

Comment: oh, i didn't know bfore this, thankyou for sharing :D